# Aligning Data When Merging Two Data Frames Together (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one DF like this entitled DF1:

```
 Words      Type    Score
 The Man    Big       7
 The Man    Small     8
 The Man    Medium    10
```

And a second DF entitled DF2:

```
 Words      Type    Score
 The Man    Big       10
 The Man    Small     12
 The Man    Medium    11
```

What I would like to do is merge these two DF together and align them as so:

```
 Words      Type    Score    Type1     Score1  
 The Man    Big       7       Big       10
 The Man    Small     8       Small     12
 The Man    Medium    10      Medium    11
```

What I am trying is this:

```
freq = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='outer', on='Words',suffixes=('', '1'))
```

but this is what the output looks like from that code:

```
  Words      Type    Score    Type1     Score1  
 The Man     Big       7      Big       10
 The Man     Big       7      Small     12
 The Man     Big       7      Medium    21
 The Man     Small     8      Big       10
 The Man     Small     8      Small     12
 The Man     Small     8      Medium    21
 The Man     Medium    10     Big       10
 The Man     Medium    10     Small     12
 The Man     Medium    10     Medium    21
```

How do I align the data to fit with my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge on both `Words` and `Type`:

```
In [63]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Words', 'Type'], suffixes=('', '1'))
Out[63]: 
  Words    Type  Score  Score1
0   Man     Big      7      10
1   Man   Small      8      12
2   Man  Medium     10      11
```

Comment: sigh...one day I'll memorize all the capabilities in Pandas and stop being tripped up by these simple functions.  But until then, its nice to know that SO has my back.  Thank you :)